# Facebook account kit is not working and getting server error 500 in release mood.How to solve?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

I tried account kit of facebook in debug mood and it works fine. Then i created new fresh app in facebook developer account and set a release key for the app and added the app id, client id and app secret. This time the sms works fine but when it hits the facebook graph api for the phone number , it gets 500 server error.

NOTE:: in debug mood the fb graph api same code is working good.